# User Creation in SVN

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I have successfully installed Tortoise SVN server on windows machine and created a repository which I am able to get latest version, check out and commit (domain users) the changes from different windows machines.

Kindly guide me in creating SVN users, groups and assigning them to the repository.

SVN Server Details
Windows 8

SVN Client Details
Windows 7

Comment: What have you installed exactly? TortoiseSVN is a client, not a server. There's no "TortoiseSVN Server".

Comment: Agreed, my mistake. I have installed Visual SVN Server and Tortoise client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you have to read [SVNBook and learn how Subversion works](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/).

TortoiseSVN is just a mere client, i.e. it does not allow you to access your local repository remotely. You have to use Subversion server to expose your repositories over the network (e.g. use Subversion + Apache HTTP Server or Subversion + `svnserve`).

You can [setup your server from the scratch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache) or use such package as [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) that allows server installation and administration to be done in very user-friendly manner.

Answer (score 0):

There are two option for authentication in Apache Subversion Http Server based :
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn

and SVNserver based : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth

TortoviseSVN is there any server as well ? I am aware about VisualSVn server and TortoviseSVN client software for windows

Regards

Jyotsna